# How does Webpack HMR interact with Vuex modules?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, hot-module-replacement, vuex-modules

I'm using **Webpack**, it's Hot Module Replacement (**HMR**) feature and **Vuex** in Vue.js app. The load sequence is as follows:

1. User clicks shared link from a message - launch loading UI and hit an API for some content
2. Content returns - initialize a Vuex submodule of the root, lets call it `subA`
3. Once it's initialized - transition the UI to another page, and display some data from `subA` using a getter.

This works **every time** under normal circumstances, but when I make file changes, save them (triggering HMR), the Vuex submodule `subA` seems to get reset - all it's properties on `state` get set to the initial values.

How is HMR interacting with Vuex and why is this happening?

Comment: hmr doesn't work with vuex. But there are workarounds. Chris fritz have some example repos.

Answer (score 1):

I am running into the same issue. This is a tricky subject.... It looks like you need to specifically tell Vuex which modules need to be hot reloaded. I don't have a good solution yet but take a look at the Vuex documentation for hot reloading Vuex modules. The solution uses Webpack's hot reload API.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/hot-reload.html